# Check if iPad has ability to route out to the Internet

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, wifi

how to check if iPad has ability to route out to the Internet? i want two different things one is to check if wifi is reachable for which i use following Rechability code, but now i want to Check if iPad has ability to route out to the Internet. How can i do that?

```
  Reachability *networkReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
NetworkStatus networkStatus = [networkReachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if (networkStatus == NotReachable) {
    NSLog(@"There IS NO internet connection");
} else {
    NSLog(@"There IS internet connection");
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use that code to find out type of connection you have on the device.

```
wan = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
NetworkStatus networkStatus = [wan currentReachabilityStatus];
if (networkStatus == ReachableViaWWAN) {

}

wifi = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
NetworkStatus networkStatus = [wifi currentReachabilityStatus];
if (networkStatus == ReachableViaWiFi) {

}
```

Comment: I don't want to check if network status is reachable via WIFI or reachable via LAN, i want to check if iPad device has ability to route to internet.

Comment: What you mean route ? :)